# Update one field of all tuples in my database (MS SQL)

Tags: sql-server

I've imported a country database from somewhere, with these fields:

```
Abbr varchar(2), FullName varchar(50)
```

An example tuple is:

```
AL, "Albania"
```

As you can see, the data in the second field is surrounded by quotation marks. I'd like to remove them, because they make the rest of my code just a little more annoying (I have to remove them programmatically each time).

Is there a microsoft sql server (2008) Update statement I can run to remove the quotation marks?

Comment: Please avoid using 'mssql' for a tag.  I know I'd prefer it to 'sqlserver', too, but there are 5000 questions tagged 'sqlserver' and this was the ONLY question tagged 'mssql', so for whatever reason the community here has organized around 'sqlserver'.

Comment: Just helping people get the taxonomist badge ;-) No worries though, the question got answered, which was my most pressing concern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET FullName = Replace(FullName, '"', '')
```